# Горизонтальный ul список с заполнением всего ряда, как правильно?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Имеется горизонтальный ul список, заданный через flex. Как грамотно указать li, чтобы они заполняли все горизонтальное пространство?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  -webkit-margin-before: 0;
  -webkit-margin-after: 0;
  -webkit-margin-start: 0;
  -webkit-margin-end: 0;
  -webkit-padding-start: 0;
}

.list {
  display: flex;
  background: #ffd3d4;
}

.item {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background: #f5c6ff;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li class="item">Главная</li>
  <li class="item">Услуги</li>
  <li class="item">Информация</li>
  <li class="item">Новости</li>
  <li class="item">Контакты</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Нужно добавить подходящее для этого свойство `flex-grow`:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.list {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  background: #ffd3d4;
}

.item {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background: #f5c6ff;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li class="item">Главная</li>
  <li class="item">Услуги</li>
  <li class="item">Информация</li>
  <li class="item">Новости</li>
  <li class="item">Контакты</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @МаксимЛенский, а что тебе мешает исправить?

Comment: @МаксимЛенский, зря...Мы ту все ради этого и собрались... Помогать друг другу, исправлять ошибки, делиться опытом...

Comment: @МаксимЛенский, на счет `margin` согласен.  А как тебя понять, что `flex-grow` не существует?  Ты о чем?

Comment: @МаксимЛенский, я лишь дописал одно свойство, код взял с вопроса=))

Comment: @МаксимЛенский, не успел сам исправить, отошёл сразу, как только ответ дал